# I am getting django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(7) error

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

```
                print(languages,type(languages), len(languages))
                self.Project = Projects(
                    name=each['name'][:20],
                    language=languages[:9],
                    About=each['description'][:60]
                )
                print(self.Project, self.Project.clean())
                print(self.Project.language)
                self.Project.save()
```

gives the error

...

```
    JavaScript CSS HTML 18418 7866 504 <class 'str'> 34
    Local-ctf-event None
    JavaScrip
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/DATA/programing/Mainsiteport/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.StringDataRightTruncation: value too long for type character varying(7)


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    ...
    ...
    ...
          File "/mnt/DATA/programing/Mainsiteport/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
            return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
          File "/mnt/DATA/programing/Mainsiteport/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
            raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
          File "/mnt/DATA/programing/Mainsiteport/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
            return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
        django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(7)
```

my models.py is

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
    
    class Projects(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(
            max_length=28
        )
        language = models.TextField(max_length=250,blank=True,null=True)
        About = models.TextField( max_length=250,blank=True,null=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return (self.name)
```

i tried to change the model declatatoin from Texfield to charfield and slugfield and change the max_length nothing seem to work
I did tried to create object from admin i get the same error,the datbase is postgresql

Comment: I'm guessing the `name` field in the Postgres table is actually `varchar(7)`. Use `psql` to do  `\d <table_name>` and see what is there.

Comment: Yep that was the issue

Comment: even though makemigrations was creating the migrations migrate wasn't applying them  , i was able to create the same model from another app and successfully migrate